# Redirect does not work

Tags: seo, htaccess, redirects

I tried to redirect a broken link onto my site by redirect :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^domian_registration\.html$ "http\:\/\/mysite\.com\/domain_registration\.html" [R=301,L]
```

But it responds with error (404 Not Found) and redirects to following URL:

```
mysite/home/[Cpanel user]/public_html/domain_registration.html
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** Why do you need `RewriteCond` here that does absolutely nothing?

**2.** Target URL should be just normal link -- no need to escape all non-alphabet characters like you do `\:\/\/`.

**3.** That directive requires **mod_rewrite** module to be enabled on your server.

That's how your rule should look like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^domian_registration\.html$ http://mysite.com/domain_registration.html [R=301,L]
```

OR as simple as (although including full domain name in URL is recommended):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^domian_registration\.html$ domain_registration.html [R=301,L]
```

---

If you do not have mod_rewrite enabled on your site, you can use this directive instead:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/domian_registration\.html$ http://mysite.com/domain_registration.html
```

---

**UPDATE:** This is an answer for your additional question:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^maghalat\.php/isfahan_articles(\d+)\.html$ /articles/isfahan_articles$1.html? [R=301,L]
```

This rule will redirect `/maghalat.php/isfahan_articles123.html?id=123` to `/articles/isfahan_articles123.html`.

Considering that source and target URLs are very similar .. and the fact that id in html file name is the same as `id=` parameter in query string, we can ignore the query string thus making the rule a bit simpler (no real need for `RewriteCond` line):

```
RewriteRule ^maghalat\.php/isfahan_articles(\d+)\.html$ /articles/isfahan_articles$1.html? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thanks , I have another question : how can I redirect mysite/maghalat.php/isfahan_articles([0-9]+).html?id=([0-9]+) to mysite/articles/isfahan_articles([0-9]+).html permanently?

Comment: 1) What is `mysite` -- a folder .. or domain name? 2) Provide an real URL example, not with `([0-9]+)`

Comment: http://myisfahan.com/maghalat.php/isfahan_articles123.html?id=123 to http://myisfahan.com/articles/isfahan_articles123.html

Comment: did you see my provided link?

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: Thanks it works properly , I had many links with high ranking on Google that dropped suddenly , do you think my ranking will back by this redirection?

Comment: Not in a week time, but eventually (2 months or so) -- yes (I mean -- if it was the only reason they it will).

Comment: I don't really know the reason of decreasing ranking of my pages but I recently (a month ago) redesign this site and add another SEO friendly link for my articles that caused duplicate links for these top ranked URLs I guess this duplicate URL caused decreasing my ranking

Comment: How can I redirect mysite.com/news/XXX.html to mysite.com/news/XXX/[news_subject].html for my Google indexed link redirection?